# How do I use Locale at 7/8 angular with fullCalendar

Tags: angular, angular-material, fullcalendar, angular7, angular7-router

I'm using fullCalendar on my angular object, I want to change my calendar to another location, but I can't understand how to do that, the fullcalendar documentation doesn't help much, I'm trying to make this froma but I can't:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZXwl.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? You should paste the code here and remove the image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make it easier to answer your questrion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change locale string like this:

```
this.options = {
    ...
    locale: 'pt-BR',
    ...
};

///locales list
af-ZA
am-ET
ar-AE
ar-BH
ar-DZ
ar-EG
ar-IQ
ar-JO
ar-KW
ar-LB
ar-LY
ar-MA
arn-CL
ar-OM
ar-QA
ar-SA
ar-SY
ar-TN
ar-YE
as-IN
az-Cyrl-AZ
az-Latn-AZ
ba-RU
be-BY
bg-BG
bn-BD
bn-IN
bo-CN
br-FR
bs-Cyrl-BA
bs-Latn-BA
ca-ES
co-FR
cs-CZ
cy-GB
da-DK
de-AT
de-CH
de-DE
de-LI
de-LU
dsb-DE
dv-MV
el-GR
en-029
en-AU
en-BZ
en-CA
en-GB
en-IE
en-IN
en-JM
en-MY
en-NZ
en-PH
en-SG
en-TT
en-US
en-ZA
en-ZW
es-AR
es-BO
es-CL
es-CO
es-CR
es-DO
es-EC
es-ES
es-GT
es-HN
es-MX
es-NI
es-PA
es-PE
es-PR
es-PY
es-SV
es-US
es-UY
es-VE
et-EE
eu-ES
fa-IR
fi-FI
fil-PH
fo-FO
fr-BE
fr-CA
fr-CH
fr-FR
fr-LU
fr-MC
fy-NL
ga-IE
gd-GB
gl-ES
gsw-FR
gu-IN
ha-Latn-NG
he-IL
hi-IN
hr-BA
hr-HR
hsb-DE
hu-HU
hy-AM
id-ID
ig-NG
ii-CN
is-IS
it-CH
it-IT
iu-Cans-CA
iu-Latn-CA
ja-JP
ka-GE
kk-KZ
kl-GL
km-KH
kn-IN
kok-IN
ko-KR
ky-KG
lb-LU
lo-LA
lt-LT
lv-LV
mi-NZ
mk-MK
ml-IN
mn-MN
mn-Mong-CN
moh-CA
mr-IN
ms-BN
ms-MY
mt-MT
nb-NO
ne-NP
nl-BE
nl-NL
nn-NO
nso-ZA
oc-FR
or-IN
pa-IN
pl-PL
prs-AF
ps-AF
pt-BR
pt-PT
qut-GT
quz-BO
quz-EC
quz-PE
rm-CH
ro-RO
ru-RU
rw-RW
sah-RU
sa-IN
se-FI
se-NO
se-SE
si-LK
sk-SK
sl-SI
sma-NO
sma-SE
smj-NO
smj-SE
smn-FI
sms-FI
sq-AL
sr-Cyrl-BA
sr-Cyrl-CS
sr-Cyrl-ME
sr-Cyrl-RS
sr-Latn-BA
sr-Latn-CS
sr-Latn-ME
sr-Latn-RS
sv-FI
sv-SE
sw-KE
syr-SY
ta-IN
te-IN
tg-Cyrl-TJ
th-TH
tk-TM
tn-ZA
tr-TR
tt-RU
tzm-Latn-DZ
ug-CN
uk-UA
ur-PK
uz-Cyrl-UZ
uz-Latn-UZ
vi-VN
wo-SN
xh-ZA
yo-NG
zh-CN
zh-HK
zh-MO
zh-SG
zh-TW
zu-ZA
```